# $f(0) = 0$ and $\nabla f(0) = 0$, what about $r^{2}f'(r)$ at $r=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $g$ be a nonnegative radial (i.e. $g(x) = g(|x|)$) smooth function with compact support on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and let $f$ be a radial solution of:
$$(-\Delta + g)f = 0$$
with $f(0) = 0$. Since $f$ is radial, this equation is given by:
$$-\frac{2}{r^{2}}\frac{d}{dr}\bigg{(}r^{2}\frac{df}{dr}\bigg{)} + g(r)f(r) = 0.$$

My question is really simple: does the condition $f(0) = 0$ imply that $\lim_{r\to 0}r^{2}\frac{df}{dr} = 0$? Of course $r^{2} \to 0$ as $r \to 0$ and also since $g$ is continuous $\lim_{r\to 0}g(r)f(r) = 0$, so that $(-\Delta f)(0) = 0$. But I cannot go any further.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that just because $f(0)=0$, doesn't mean that $df(0)/dr=0$. If $df(0)/dr$ tends to infinity, you have a $0 \cdot \infty$ problem. So essentially, you need to know the value of $df(r)/dr$ as $r$ tends to zero to solve this problem. In other words, it is not necessarily true that $\lim_{r \to 0}r^2{df(r) \over dr}$ is equal to zero.

However, if for example $df(0)/dr$ is equal to zero, you can simplify your problem the following way. Let's rewrite your equation:

$$ -2 \Bigg ( {2 \over r}{df(r) \over dr} + {d^2f(r) \over dr^2}\Bigg ) +g(r)f(r)=0 \tag 1$$

Using Maclaurin's expansion we get:

$$ {df(r) \over dr}= {df(0) \over dr}+r \cdot {d^2f(0) \over dr^2}= r \cdot {d^2f(0) \over dr^2}\tag 2$$

Inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields:

$$-2 \Bigg( 2{d^2f(0) \over dr^2} + {d^2f(0) \over dr^2} \Bigg )+g(0)f(0)=0 \tag 3$$

which means:

$$ {d^2f(0) \over dr^2} = 0 \tag 4$$

because $f(0)$ is equal to zero. However, if you don't know anything about the value of $df(0)/dr$, this does not apply. In your title, you are saying that $\nabla f(0)=0$, meaning $df(0)/dr=0$. That means that $\Delta f(0)$ really is equal to zero.

On a side note, the Laplacian is defined as $\Delta =d^2(.)/dr^2 + {1/r}\cdot d(.)/dr$. I don't know why are you scaling it with $2$. Also, $r$ does not need to be squared.